# Deleting item from SQLite deletes next item

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have wrote code to delete an item from SQLite database  and from listview, it always deletes next item. For example I have 3 items to delete ("1", "2" and "3")

I press delete on item "1" but it deletes item "2"

I press delete item "2", it deletes "3" but,

If I press delete "3" application crashes. I don't understand what is wrong. when I write

```java
db.delete(books.get(info.position-1))
```

inside MainActivity.java it gives me crash when I try to delete (app stops working).

**DBAdapter.java**

```java
public void delete(String name)throws SQLException {
    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    if (db == null) {
        return;
    }
    String[] whereArgs = new String[] { name };
    db.delete("m_TB", "NAME"+ "=?", whereArgs);
    db.close();
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```java
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.add("Delete");
}

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    String name = info.toString();
    if (item.getTitle().equals("Delete")) {
        db.delete(books.get(info.position));
        books.remove(item);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: The `position` from the `ListView` is zero-based. That is, the first item has position 0, the second is position 1, the third is 2, etc.

Comment: I would let the book object keep its own id, then get the book from the listview and get its id with which you delete from db

Comment: so what code i should use then?